# URL scheme to call the Microsoft Edge App?

Tags: android, microsoft-edge, url-scheme

I want to have a **URL link with a specific scheme** to open a web page but exclusively in **Microsoft Edge**, on Android.

For iOS, there is such thing : [Open URL in NEW Microsoft Edge window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436895/open-url-in-new-microsoft-edge-window), 
it is

> microsoft-edge-https://

Is there are similar URL i can use to call Microsoft Edge **on Android**?
Thanks a million...

Comment: are you calling this from inside an app you are creating?  If so, you can send your intent to a specific reciever instead of broadcasting it.

Comment: Thanks John.It would be a URL link in an app where i don't control the specifics. I can just add some text content and link. So i don't have the luck to be able to use intents.

Comment: well, i like Yu Zhou's answer, but if this is a managed device you can actually set the built-in routing in settings to always open edge upon the first launch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try with `microsoft-edge:some website` and it works. I test the following page in Firefox on Android and it can open Microsoft Edge when I click the link:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="microsoft-edge:https://www.google.com">link</a>
</body>
</html>
```