# Can open new window in different browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser

My company is using a website that only works in Explorer. The new application needs to be linked from the existing browser, but the new application does not support Explorer.
Is it possible to open a new window in Edge or Chrome when a specific button is pressed in Internet Explorer? Is it possible using JavaScript or else?
Thank you :D

Search everywhere but can't find solution...

Comment: For Edge, [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846066/url-scheme-to-call-the-microsoft-edge-app). I'm not sure if there is a URI scheme for Chrome. This does of course require Edge to be installed.

Comment: No, that's not possible (unless provided by the application as a scheme, but that's not possible with Explorer). You, as a website, have no access to tell the system to do things in other programs at all. Or even open other programs. Let alone a browser that is no longer supported or updated.

Comment: Can I do it like below?
<a href="microsoft-edge:http://www.google.com">Test</a>

Comment: If the OS has microsoft edge, and the URI scheme is registered, etc... There are too many caveats and no guarantees so you can never promise that this feature will work as intended. All you can do, and the best you could really do, is to check the userAgent to see if you are in the right browsers and otherwise recommend using another. However, with todays modern web standards, your site _should work in every browser_ almost 99% the same. And please, please, don't user Internet Explorer.